# Return specific variable of Enum, determined by variable with the same name of another Enum?

Tags: c#

I wonder if there is any way to write the followig in a few lines instead of using all cases. Both `CategoryType` and `AnimalSpecies` are `Enum`s.

```
private AnimalSpecies GetAnimalSpeciesBasedOnCategoryType(CategoryType categoryType)
{
    switch (categoryType)
    {
        case CategoryType.Reptile :
            return AnimalSpecies.Reptile;

        case CategoryType.Bird:
            return AnimalSpecies.Bird;
        case CategoryType.Mammal:
            return AnimalSpecies.Mammal;
        case CategoryType.Insect:
            return AnimalSpecies.Insect;
        case CategoryType.Marine:
            return AnimalSpecies.Marine;

        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Category doesn't exist.Something wrong in programming code");
            return AnimalSpecies.Marine;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dictionary data structure?

Comment: This is probably better asked on stack

Comment: If not having a corresponding category is a programming error, then the two Enums are effectively identical, and there is no sense in having them. Why do you need two different Enum types? Are you trying to store information in the type of an attribute? that would better be done in its value.

Comment: Your `default` case should throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about (untested not near a computer at the moment)

```
   return (AnimalSpecies )Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimalSpecies ), categoryType.ToString());
```

Comment: This looks correct, assuming the names of both enums always exactly match.

Comment: @Anders - .NET 4 introduced `Enum.TryParse()`. You could use that and then throw the same exception as shown in the `default` case in your question.